# SAS: generating an output database following several proc procedures

Tags: database, sas

I am still new at SAS and I was wondering how I can do the following:

Say that I have a database with the following info:

```
Time_during_the day    date    prices   volume_traded
930am                  sep02    42            300
10am                   sep02    41            200
..4pm                  sep02    40            200
930am                  sep03    40            500
10am                   sep03    41            100
..4pm                  sep03    40            350
.....
```

What I want is to take the average of the total daily volume and divide this number by 50 (always). So say avg.daily vol./50 = V; and what I want is to record the price/time/date at every interval of size V. Now, say that V=500, I start by recording the first price,time,and date in my database and then record the same info 500 volume trade later. It is possible that on one day that the traded volume is say 300 and half of it will cover the v=500, the other 150 will be use to fill up up the following interval.

How can I get this information in one database?
Thank you!

Comment: I have ideas on how to do this but first a few more questions. I'm not sure how you have N price/times per day.  Do you mean that you're repeating this operation for N=1 to 50, each day? Or is N always 50? Once we clear this stuff up I think I can put something together.

Comment: @sparc_spread I realized I have done a mistake in my explanation (I will update the post above). What I want is to take the average daily volume and divide this number by 50 (always). So say avg.daily vol./50 = V; and what I want is to record the price/time/date at every interval of size V. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may mean that V = (sum daily vol / 50), not (avg / 50).  I did with sum in the answer.

Comment: @sparc_spread V would have to be the average of total daily volume / 50. Thanks! I updated my post above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your input dataset is called tick_data, and that it is sorted by both `date` and `time_during_the_day`.  Then here's what I got:

```
%LET n = 50;

/* Calculate V - the breakpoint size */
PROC SUMMARY DATA=tick_data;
    BY date;

    OUTPUT OUT = temp_1 
           SUM (volume_traded)= volume_traded_agg;
RUN;
DATA temp_2 ;
    SET temp_1;
    V = volume_traded_agg / &n;
RUN;

/* Merge it into original dataset so that it is available */
DATA temp_3;
    MERGE tick_data temp_2;
    BY date;
RUN;

/* Final walk through tick data to output at breakpoints */
DATA results 
    /* Comment out the KEEP to see what is happening under the hood */
    (KEEP=date time_during_the_day price volume_traded)
;
    SET temp_3;

    /* The IF FIRST will not work without the BY below */
    BY date;

    /* Stateful counters */
    RETAIN 
            volume_cumulative
            breakpoint_next
            breakpoint_counter
    ;

    /* Reset stateful counters at the beginning of each day */
    IF (FIRST.date) THEN DO;
            volume_cumulative   = 0;
            breakpoint_next     = V;
            breakpoint_counter  = 0;
    END;

    /* Breakpoint test */
    volume_cumulative = volume_cumulative + volume_traded;
    IF (breakpoint_counter <= &n  AND volume_cumulative >= breakpoint_next) THEN DO;
        OUTPUT;
        breakpoint_next = breakpoint_next + V;
        breakpoint_counter = breakpoint_counter + 1;
    END;
RUN;
```

The key SAS language feature to keep in mind for the future is the use of `BY`, `FIRST`, and `RETAIN` together.  This enables stateful walks through data like this one.  Conditional `OUTPUT` also figures here.

Note that whenever you use `BY <var>`, the dataset must be sorted on a key that includes `<var>`. In the case of `tick_data` and all intermediate temporary tables, it is.

### Additional: Alternative V

In order to make V equal the (average total daily volume / n), replace the matching code block above with this one:

```
. . . . . .
/* Calculate V - the breakpoint size */
PROC SUMMARY DATA=tick_data;
    BY date;

    OUTPUT OUT = temp_1 
           SUM (volume_traded)= volume_traded_agg;
RUN;
PROC SUMMARY DATA = temp_1
    OUTPUT OUT = temp_1a
           MEAN (volume_traded_agg) =;
RUN;
DATA temp_2 ;
    SET temp_1a;
    V = volume_traded_agg / &n;
RUN;

/* Merge it into original dataset so that it is available */
DATA temp_3 . . . . . .
 . . . . . .
```

Basically you just insert a second `PROC SUMMARY` to take the mean of the sums. Notice how there is no `BY` statement because we're averaging over the whole set, not by any groupings or buckets. Also notice the `MEAN (...) =` without a name after the `=`. That will make the output variable have the same name as the input variable.

Comment: thanks! well explained! How can I modify the value of V where V = average total of daily trades / &n? Can I do it in the proc summary step?

Comment: Glad to help. Can you give me an example of how you would want to change V?

Comment: Now the code is setup to sum all the trades per day and then divide by 50. I want to sum all the trades per day, take the average of the sums (of all days) and then divide by 50. Thanks!

Comment: So this would be one single output, correct?  Or do you mean use this new average as the new V?

Comment: Yes one single output for V. My total daily volume varies, hence I want the average of total daily volume and then divide this by 50 to get V. Thanks a lot sparc!

Comment: thank you very much! Very helpful and you provided me with a lot of insights for how to work more efficiently with SAS.

Comment: I would like to make a small adjustment. In the code `...volume_cumulative >= breakpoint_next then ouput` I would like to take the difference between the volume_cumulative and breakpoint_next at 'output' and subtract this amount from `breakpoint_next = breakpoint_next + V;` since if the cumulative vol. was higher than the breakpoint, I want to carry on the difference to the following breakpoint ->new breakpoint is smaller than simply adding V. I tried a couple of options with diff, lag, in the difference and substract it from the new breakpoint point but no luck. Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried using `RETAIN`?  That would seem like the best way to carry the difference to the next iteration.  You're already using `RETAIN` for the volume_cumulative and other variables, so just add this new difference variable on to the statement and make sure to clear it in the `IF FIRST.` clause.  To get a picture of how `RETAIN` works, comment out the `KEEP` clause, which was cosmetically hiding all the temporary retained variables, and look at the resulting dataset.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I went through your code but on a piece a paper and saw that the code does exactly 100% what I wanted. Sorry for all the trouble and thanks again for all the insights.

Comment: Glad everything is working!  No trouble at all.  My pleasure to help.